# Copying a Lookup Field in SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, designer-workflow, workflow-variable

I am trying to read a "`Lookup" Column called 'Color`' from a list and simply copy it into another "Text" column called 'Scheme' through SharePoint Designer 2013.

In Designer, doing

- "Set Scheme to `CurrentItem:Color`" does NOT work.

I also tried creating a 'String' Variable called 'SchemeVar' and did:

- `"Set Variable:SchemeVar to CurrentItem:Color`

This also does not work.  My workflow gets suspended.

My GOAL is to be able to use the Lookup field content in an email but it is not coming through for me.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated!!

**PS:** In designer, my Lookup field's "`Return field as" is 'Lookup Value (as Text)`' and can not be changed.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it by doing something like this

[image]

In my case I update Title column "Text Field" to set the value from a lookup column

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Unfortunately when I try this, my workflow gets suspended. I also used this link as a reference:

https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28338394/Extracting-text-from-a-lookup-field-in-a-SharePoint-2013-workflow.html

But it seems at the very bottom, that some users are still getting workflow suspended, like I am.